# HTTPS and how to reference files and images

Tags: css, security, http, https

How should I reference my css file (which is in the non-secure area) from a webpage in the secure area. I've considered duplicating it (moving one in to the secure area) but this seems very inefficient.

Any advice much appreciated.
(p.s. there will most likely be a few follow up questions ha ha)

Comment: Can you not address the style sheet through `https://` as well?

Comment: it must work but you should instruct webserver to accept or to transmit over https (443 port)

Comment: You will need to make it work if you want to avoid "mixed content" warnings from Internet Explorer. Anyway, it's very unclear what you are asking about - is your question about how to set up the web server so it serves SSL data from the same web root as the non-SSL one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always avoid the issue by using a relative/rooted path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/screen.css">
```

If you must use a full URL, I'm not sure *why* you can't use the https protocol (which is the correct solution), but there's one more option: don't specify a protocol at all.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//example.com/css/screen.css">
```

http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

> If the browser is viewing that current page in through HTTPS, then it'll request that asset with the HTTPS protocol, otherwise it'll typically* request it with HTTP. This prevents that awful "This Page Contains Both Secure and Non-Secure Items" error message in IE, keeping all your asset requests within the same protocol.

However:

> **Caveat**: When used on a `<link>` or @import for a stylesheet, IE7 and IE8 download the file twice. All other uses, however, are just fine.

So if you must specify a full URL, the best/proper way is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/css/screen.css">
```

There's really no alternative. Relative paths to images and resources in the CSS file itself should work just fine with either approach, and won't trigger the security error. If you need absolute URLs in the CSS file, then you can use the same trick.

Comment: But he's saying he can't do this (serve CSS files through SSL, that is). That's what makes me wonder what this question actually is about.

Comment: "Can't"? Why even ask the question then? Protocol relative URL will work with or without https, that's the point - he won't have to change anything when switching from http to https. I see the comment above `"No - this wouldn't work"`, but it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: yeah, the question doesn't make much sense at the moment. He'll need to clarify. (Your answer may well be what he's looking for!)