# How do I secure a stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, magento

Can anyone clarify this message? I think it's why I lost all my styling on my shopping cart.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.redsgear.com/checkout/cart/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to post proper questions.

Comment: Where is that located?

Comment: When you went to post your question there was a big box on the right: How to ask a question. The issue here is, questions should be self-contained. They should not expect people to visit your web site and reverse-engineer what's going on there.

Comment: Thank you, I attempted to provide images, but was kept from doing so, as my reputation score wasn't high enough, hence my issue.

Comment: The stupidly easy way: add an s: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTPS and how to reference files and images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019527/https-and-how-to-reference-files-and-images)

Comment: In viewing the source code, all of the content is referenced securely through HTTPS. Anyone know why this happens all of a sudden that it now isn't being served over HTTPS?

Comment: Why do you have more than 30 external JS/CSS files being loaded? Stop that.

Answer (score 11):

change `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald` to `//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald`

Answer (score 1):

*simply change HTTP to HTTPS in your source code.*

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue just recently using the ionicframework CDN, hosting files with GitHub pages and lalna s m's method above worked.

```
Changed http: 
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

To https:
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```